# Cannot set needsUpdate to true

Tags: node.js, three.js

I'm trying to set needsUpdate to true after I've modified the existing Texture

I've tried setting the needsUpdate to true

var meshes = this.sceneObject3D.children;

```
    meshes.map((mesh) => {
      if(mesh.material.map) {
        mesh.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    })
```

the needsUpdate value still remains undefined after assignment

Comment: Instead of debugging the `needsUpdate` flag, it might make more sense to verify if `Texture.version` has increased after setting the flag. If so, the texture's data will be uploaded to the GPU.

Comment: Try to set `mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;` , not the map.